# ajax request succeeds redraw datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im trying to redraw a datatable after the approve button has been clicked and once the ajax request succeeds.

Everything works in the click function (it saves to db, it animates, it slides up) but the 
table does not redraw.

Does any body have any ideas as to why its not working?

```
  $('a.approve').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&approve='+ parent.attr('id').replace('record-','')+'&employee='+ parent.attr('title')+'&acyear=' + parent.attr('lang'),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        var $aTable= $("#table_a").dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
        var $bTable= $("#table_b").dataTable( { bRetrieve : true } );
        $aTable.fnDraw();
        $bTable.fnDraw();
        });

      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I just suffered through this so I thought I'd leave the answer here.

By default JQuery does not prevent caching of ajax responses. Chrome and Firefox seem to not cache these calls anyway, so they update fine. IE, on the other hand, always caches ajax responses and will not refresh them even with a hard page refresh. The solution is to always include a cache: "false" setting in your ajax calls, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    url: 'index.php',
    data: 'ajax=1',
    success: function() {
      ...
    }
);
```

Datatables throw an extra twist into this: by default they turn off caching for you (since v. 1.7). So if you just set an ajax url, a datatable should update ok:

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "getAssayBatches.json",  // URL that retrieves the data
    // datatable leaves caching off by default. Table refreshes ok!
});
```

HOWEVER, if you need to do some extra processing and overwrite the 'fnServerData' function, you lose the default cache setting, meaning caching is turned back on:

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "getAssayBatches.json",  // URL that retrieves the data

    // the following parameter turns caching back on, meaning stale data in IE!
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
            var data = {"aaData": json};
            fnCallback(data);
        });
    }
});
```

So you need to put cache: false here too to ensure the table gets updated:

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "getAssayBatches.json",  // URL that retrieves the data

    // same ajax call as above, but this time with cache: false 
    // to ensure the table gets updated
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: sSource,
            data: aoData,
            success: function (json) {
                var data = {"aaData": json};
                fnCallback(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hopes this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see enough of your code to understand your precise need.

I guess your `parent` var represents a row in one of your dataTables, and that you want to delete it from the dataTable.

dataTable keeps an inner cache of its data, and calling `parent.remove()` will not update this cache.

If you want to delete a row from a dataTable, you should use the API function [fnDeleteRow](http://datatables.net/api#fnDeleteRow) :

```
// remove your "parent.remove()" line
$aTable.fnDeleteRow(parent[0])
```

Comment: The delete functionality works fine and i have managed to remove the row. The bit i struggled with was getting new data after i had done the delete (the delete recalculates a field value and saves to db)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get new table data from the database, your `index.php` need to return the table values as a JSON:

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "2",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "2",
  "aaData": [
    [
      "Gecko",
      "Firefox 1.0",
      "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "1.7",
      "A"
    ],
    [
      "Gecko",
      "Netscape Navigator 9",
      "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "1.8",
      "A"
    ]       ]
}
```

and the success part:

```
success: function(json) {
        parent.slideUp(300, function() {
            parent.remove();

            var obj = JSON.parse(json);//get new data
            oTable.fnClearTable();//clear table
            for (x in obj.aaData)
                oTable.fnAddData(obj[x]); //populate table

            //redo another ajax if you have several table.
        });
```

If only 1 row is changed then delete that row, return that row from the server in JSON and re-insert that row in the table.

Answer (score -1):

**`oTable.fnReloadAjax();`** after success result rebind table

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function (oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw) {
    if (typeof sNewSource != 'undefined' && sNewSource != null) {
        oSettings.sAjaxSource = sNewSource;
    }
    this.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, true);
    var that = this;
    var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
    var aData = [];

    this.oApi._fnServerParams(oSettings, aData);

    oSettings.fnServerData(oSettings.sAjaxSource, aData, function (json) {
        /* Clear the old information from the table */
        that.oApi._fnClearTable(oSettings);

        /* Got the data - add it to the table */
        var aData = (oSettings.sAjaxDataProp !== "") ?
            that.oApi._fnGetObjectDataFn(oSettings.sAjaxDataProp)(json) : json;

        for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
            that.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, aData[i]);
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        that.fnDraw();

        if (typeof bStandingRedraw != 'undefined' && bStandingRedraw === true) {
            oSettings._iDisplayStart = iStart;
            that.fnDraw(false);
        }

        that.oApi._fnProcessingDisplay(oSettings, false);

        /* Callback user function - for event handlers etc */
        if (typeof fnCallback == 'function' && fnCallback != null) {
            fnCallback(oSettings);
        }
    }, oSettings);
}
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response, would i use  $adwpTable.fnReloadAjax(); instead of the 4 lines underneath parent.remove(); then include your answer above the $('a.approve').click(function(e) {}

Comment: im not using server side scripting for this table so fnReloadAjax() wont work, or will it? Anyway cant get it to work. Just want to refresh the table to the current data